# Unity 2D Rotating Enemy Towards Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and am working on a 2D top down shooter. I have written a script for the enemy to rotate to the player when they have a line of sight. What I am trying to do now is make it so that when the player enters the enemies line of sight, the enemy doesn't instantly snap facing the player and instead rotates quickly to face them. My current code to do this is in the while loop of my script and causes Unity to crash when the player enters line of sight of the enemy, any idea what I'm doing wrong? My script works fine without the while loop and its contents BTW.

'''c#

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 playerDir = playerLocation.position - this.transform.position;
    float angle = (Mathf.Atan2(playerDir.y, playerDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    if (canSeePlayer())
    {
        while (angle - rb.rotation < 10f || angle-rb.rotation > 10f)
        {

            rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation + 1);
        }
        rb.MoveRotation(angle - 90);
    }
}

private bool canSeePlayer()
{
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, playerLocation.position - this.transform.position);
    Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, playerLocation.position - this.transform.position);
    Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject);
    if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

many physics component it work on fixed update
and many method ***NOT*** make change immediately

for example :
you can test by using this code

```
var rotation = Rigidbody.rotation; // before
Rigidbody.MoveRotation(5);
var newRotation = Rigidbody.rotation; // after
```

after you call rigibody.moveRotation (on line 2) the rotation is still equal newRotation and you will see update on the next fixed update
that why Unity crash (becuase infinite while loop, you rotation not update)

For more information :
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe Mathf.Lerp is what you're looking for, it allows to smooth out changes in values without overshooting them. In your FixedUpdate try this:

```
Vector2 playerDir = playerLocation.position - this.transform.position;
float angle = (Mathf.Atan2(playerDir.y, playerDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
float rotationSpeed = 1f;
rb.rotation = Mathf.Lerp(rb.rotation, angle, rotationSpeed);
```

Of course you are welcome to adjust `rotationSpeed` to your liking, as well as extract it to a class variable editable within the editor.

Regarding your game freezing, please note that your `while` exit condition is not so well defined:

```
while (angle - rb.rotation < 10f || angle-rb.rotation > 10f)
```

Note that if you'll start with an `angle` less by 10 than `rb.rotation` you end up increasing `rb.rotation` furthermore in the loop thus creating an endless loop with no exit condition.

Example:
`angle = 0` and `rb.rotation = 15f`

```
0. angle - rb.rotation = -15 (less than 10f) => execute loop => rb.rotation++
1. angle - rb.rotation = -16 (less than 10f) => execute loop => rb.rotation++
2. angle - rb.rotation = -17 (less than 10f) => execute loop => rb.rotation++
3. ...
```